# How do I slice an array at a chosen dimension?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

Let's say I have an multidimensional numpy array A. I'm trying to get slices of A in whatever dimension I choose, e.g. if `A` is a 3D array and I am given some integer `layer` and some dimension `dim`:

If dim = 2, select A[:,:,layer]

If dim = 1, select A[:,layer,:]

If dim = 0, select A[layer,:,:]

For my case, A may have many dimensions to choose from so I don't want to have to write this manually. What is a simple, readable way of doing this?

Comment: `np.take` may suit your needs.

Comment: "A call such as np.take(arr, indices, axis=3) is equivalent to arr[:,:,:,indices,...]"

Oh, this sounds like exactly what I need. Thank you!
Sorry, I didn't mean to ask a question for which there was a function for already.

Comment: Please note that this only works for advanced indexing. It does not work for slices.